# Calling a button in Fragment view from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, fragment

I want to reach fragment item in Activity method but i get a null pointer error.

**Fragment Class**

```
 Button button;

 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
      button= view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    return view;
    }

    public Button getButton(){
            return button;
    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = (Fragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.Framelayout);

fragment.getButton().setText("Test");
```

**LOGCAT**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
 'android.widget.Button com.example.android.fragment.Fragment.getButton()' 
 on a null object reference
        at 
 com.example.android.MainActivity$1$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:141)
```

Comment: how did you attach the fragment?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean.

Comment: mean did you add TAG while adding the fragment

Comment: No I did not add.

Comment: ill post an answer about this

Comment: i think " button= view.findViewById(R.id.button);" not called in activity.

Comment: You can also use like this fragment.button.setText("Test");

Answer (score 0):

For adding the fragment

```
private void addFragment(FragmentManager manager)
{
    YOURFRAGMENT fragment= new YOURFRAGMENT();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(CONTAINER-ID,fragment,YOURFRAGMENT.class.getSimpleName()).commitNow();
}
```

for getting the fragment

```
 private void getFragment(FragmentManager manager,String TAG){
          YOURFRAGMENT fragment= (YOURFRAGMENT) manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG);
       if(fragment!=null){
       //access button here
       }
}
```

to get yours

```
getFragment(fragmentManager, YOURFRAGMENT.class.getSimpleName())k
```

Comment: where . did you get this?

Comment: Yes. MainActivity.class .

Comment: please call `fragment.getButton();` in the getFragment method

Comment: Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment");
      if (fragment instanceof AnaSayfa ) {
          fragment.getButton().setText("Test");
      }
Cannot resolve method 'getButton()'

Comment: where // access button here

Comment: Make sure the AnaSyfa fragment has the `getButton()`

Comment: " //access button here" This part doesn't work. So I get no error. But it's not what I want.

Comment: I would also suggest to modify the fragment view by creating a setter method in it and invoke the method from activity with passing the desired data to be set .

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Fragment` using `TAG`

```
String TAG="YourTAG";
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment, TAG)
        .commit();
```

You can invoke a method from your activity like this

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
if (fragment instanceof YourFragmentClass ) {
    fragment.getButton().setText("Test");
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -2):

try with getFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: getFragmentManager() is deprecated.